# Facebook login log missing browser data

Tags: facebook, security

In my downloaded Facebook log, in the log in list, there is one line that says:

> Session updated
>   Friday, April 21, 2017 at 12:42pm UTC+01
>   Browser:

The Browser part is blank, how can that be?
Is there any explanation for it?

Answer (score 1):

It could be any number of things. It's obviously relying on parsing the browser data from the [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string header that the browser sends. Maybe the algorithm to parse that data failed. Maybe the browser failed to send it properly. Maybe it wasn't a browser at all, but a third-party application that you've given permission to log into your Facebook account.